# passing a parameter to a pred function in a thrush expression

Tags: clojure

Given a thrush operator, I have a filter expression as one of the forms. The pred function itself needs to be passed a fixed parameter as below, where I want to pass 4 to the pred function and not to the filter function. How do I do that ?

```
(->> (a 2) (b 3) (filter pred? 4)))
```

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `pred?` takes 2 parameters, first any value (in you example 4) another is the value that is passed from `filter` function for each element in the sequence.

```
(->> (a 2) (b 3) (filter (partial pred? 4))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an anonymous function:

```
(->> (a 2) (b 3) (filter #(pred? % 4)))
```

Where the `%` marks the spot, where the item to be filtered is passed to the predicate.